# Rolling average base on two columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to get a rolling sum for each month base on weeks.
Here is what my df looks like

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[ 30, 20,15, 10, 20, 20,5,15,20,10,10, 30, 20,15, 10], ['red','red','red','red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue','Green', 'Green', 'Green'],['Feb', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar']], names=['number', 'color', 'Mon'])).reset_index()
df
number  color   mon     0 
30      red     Feb     1
20      red     Feb     2
15      red     Mar     1
10      red     Mar     2
20      red     Mar     3
20      red     Mar     4
5       blue    Feb     1
15      blue    Feb     2
20      blue    Mar     1
10      blue    Mar     2
10      blue    Mar     3
30      blue    Mar     4
20      Green   Feb     1
15      Green   Mar     1
10      Green   Mar     2
```

I want to get the rolling sum for each month for each color base on that month's week.
For the color red and mon Feb 1st week 30 and 2nd week 50 (30+20). For-Mar it should be for red 15,25,45,65

```py
number  color   mon     0   rolling
30      red     Feb     1   30
20      red     Feb     2   50
15      red     Mar     1   15
10      red     Mar     2   25
20      red     Mar     3   45
20      red     Mar     4   65
5       blue    Feb     1   5
15      blue    Feb     2   20
20      blue    Mar     1   20
10      blue    Mar     2   30
10      blue    Mar     3   40
30      blue    Mar     4   70
20      Green   Feb     1   20
15      Green   Mar     1   15
10      Green   Mar     2   25
```

I'm trying to use group by with rolling window with and without lambda but it didn't work out

```py
df.groupby(by=['color','Mon']).rolling(window=2).sum()
# also below command
df.groupby(by=['color','Mon']).apply(lambda x: x.rolling(2).sum())
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `.cumsum()`:

```py
df['rolling'] = df.groupby(['color', 'Mon'])['number'].cumsum()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    number  color  Mon  0  rolling
0       30    red  Feb  1       30
1       20    red  Feb  2       50
2       15    red  Mar  1       15
3       10    red  Mar  2       25
4       20    red  Mar  3       45
5       20    red  Mar  4       65
6        5   blue  Feb  1        5
7       15   blue  Feb  2       20
8       20   blue  Mar  1       20
9       10   blue  Mar  2       30
10      10   blue  Mar  3       40
11      30   blue  Mar  4       70
12      20  Green  Feb  1       20
13      15  Green  Mar  1       15
14      10  Green  Mar  2       25
```